# PHP inclusion behaving oddly with multiple includes

Tags: php, include

I have the following code:

```
if (include_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/file.php')
    || include_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/local/file.php')
    )
{
```

This causes an error because PHP tries to include `"1"` (presumably `dirname(__FILE__).'/file.php' || dirname(__FILE__).'/local/file.php'`)

Commenting out the second line makes this work as intended, other than the fact it won't use the second file. Do I really need to use `elseif` and code duplication here, or is there a way to get this working?

> $ php --version
>   PHP 5.2.6-3ubuntu4.2 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.6.2 (cli) (built: Aug 21 2009 19:14:44)
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2008 Zend Technologies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group the `include` statements:

```
if ( (include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/file.php')
      ||
     (include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/local/file.php')
   )
```

See [example #4](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) in the manual page:

```
<?php
// won't work, evaluated as include(('vars.php') == 'OK'), i.e. include('')
if (include('vars.php') == 'OK') {
    echo 'OK';
}

// works
if ((include 'vars.php') == 'OK') {
    echo 'OK';
}
?>
```

Comment: This is... counter-intuitive to say the least. A thousand curses on PHP's 'language constructs'.

Comment: Indeed, but that's one of the main traits of PHP :). Anyway, I'd just assign the return value of the statements to some temp variables, and use those inside the `if` test.

Comment: Alright, I have to ask: Which is one of the main traits of PHP? Being counter-intuitive, or using language constructs instead of actual functions?

Comment: Also, the main reason I chose to do it this way was because I only wanted the first of the two pages to run (if both were actually there)

Comment: The trait would be, indeed, that it is counter-intuitive, or rather inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

Try using parentheses to subdue the operator precedence.

```
if ( (include_once('xml.php')) || (include_once('xml.php')) ) {
    echo 'bah';
}
```